# How to get the position of a dynamically added control in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, button, position

I am facing an issue to get the position of a dynamically added button during runtime. Please find the below code.

```
foreach (string subfolder in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
        {
            Button btnSubfolder = new Button();
            btnSubfolder.Name = "btnsubfolder" + column.ToString();
            btnSubfolder.Content = subfolder.Substring(subfolder.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
            btnSubfolder.Margin = new Thickness(15, 15, 10, 0);
            btnSubfolder.Width = 200;
            btnSubfolder.Height = 50;
            btnSubfolder.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            btnSubfolder.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, column);
            grdsbFolders.Children.Add(btnSubfolder);
            var location = btnSubFolder.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0)); //here i am getting the same position for all the added controls;
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Adding all the buttons to the same grid would actually position them at the same location.

Comment: @chrille, can you help me to solve the problem?

Comment: please refer to my answer.

Comment: Are you just adding buttons inside a column all in one row or each button should be in a different row?

Comment: @mm8, Its working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to measure and arrange the `Grid` before you can get the actual location of the `Button`:

```
foreach (string subfolder in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
{
    Button btnSubfolder = new Button();
    btnSubfolder.Name = "btnsubfolder" + column.ToString();
    btnSubfolder.Content = subfolder.Substring(subfolder.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
    btnSubfolder.Margin = new Thickness(15, 15, 10, 0);
    btnSubfolder.Width = 200;
    btnSubfolder.Height = 50;
    btnSubfolder.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    btnSubfolder.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, column);
    grdsbFolders.Children.Add(btnSubfolder);

    grdsbFolders.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
    grdsbFolders.Arrange(new Rect());
    var location = btnSubfolder.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), grdsbFolders);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding controls to a grid without specifying column or row will position them all at the same location in the grid (0,0). Use another parent control to position the controls in a different way or specify the column and row in the grid.

Use `StackPanel` to position the controls either vertically or horizontally. You can also have a look at the `DockPanel`

Horizontal:

<kbd>Button</kbd> <kbd>Button</kbd> <kbd>Button</kbd>

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
  <Button>Btn1</Button>
  <Button>Btn2</Button>
  <Button>Btn3</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

or vertical:

<kbd>Button</kbd>
<kbd>Button</kbd>
<kbd>Button</kbd>

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
  <Button>Btn1</Button>
  <Button>Btn2</Button>
  <Button>Btn3</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I am adding it to a specific column. Check my code. btnSubfolder.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, column)

Comment: Yes, but the same column for each iteration?